# React useCallback with onClick not working. Rerenders child component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

TimeChild re-renders in below image even after using useCallback

[image]

Comment: That sounds correct to me. The standard react behavior is that if a parent component (Time) renders, its children (a div, a button, an h2, and TimeChild) render too. Did you mean to use React.memo on TimeChild?

Comment: @NicholasTower Thanks. I wanted to stop the re-rendering of child component i.e TimeChild hence i used useCallback. Do I need to use React memo as well ?

Answer (score 2):

When Time sets state, then Time is going to rerender. Then, unless you do something to stop it, all of its children will rerender too. If you want to stop a child from rerendering, then the child component needs to use React.memo.

```
const TimeChild = React.memo(() => {
  // ...
});
```

If you do this, then when TimeChild would render, it will first do an === comparison between each of its old props and each of its new props. If they are all the same, TimeChild will skip rendering.

The only role that `useCallback` plays in this is if TimeChild receives a function as a prop. If it does, then you need to make sure it receives the *same* function each time, or React.Memo will never be able to skip rendering because its props keep changing. But in your example there are no props at all being passed to TimeChild, so `useCallback` is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'useCallback' in this way :

```
    import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
    
    const App = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
    
      const callBckValue = useCallback(() => {
        setCount((count) => count + 1);
      }, []);
    
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{count}</h2>
          <button type="button" onClick={callBckValue}>
            Click Me
          </button>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: I understand this however if you see my screenshot I want to prevent re-rendering for the TimeChild Component

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to be aware, only in special situation, it makes sense to stop child component from re-rendering. If your case is not that special, that might not be a good idea.

Secondly, if you are sure you have to do it, use [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo), the usage is pretty like `componentShouldUpdate` in class component